# wordpress dependent dropdownlist using post type is not working

Tags: php, ajax, javascript

wordpress dependent drop down list using post type is not working in ajax.

I need a ddl value from another ddl in post type.

i have 2 post type department and doctors, when i select a department in drop down list i need the doctors in that department using ajax and not by refresh

**ajax**

```
$('#dpt').change(function () {
            var dpt = $(this).val();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                data: {id: dpt},
                success: function (data) {   
//                    alert(data);
                    $('#response').text('dpt : ' + data);
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

Select Doctors
         'doctors',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'dptmnt',
                    'value' => $dpt,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                'order' => 'ASC'
            ),
        );
        $events = new WP_Query($args);
        while ($events->have_posts()):
            $events->the_post();
            ?>
            ">

**HTML**

Select Department
         'dpt',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );
        $events = new WP_Query($args);
        while ($events->have_posts()):
            $events->the_post();
            ?>
            ">

**AJX**

$(function () {
        $("select[name='dp']").change(function () {
            var str = "";
            $("select[name='dp'] option:selected").each(function () {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";

            });

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $("form#a").serialize(),

                success: function (data) {
//                    alert(data);
//                    jQuery(".res").html(data);

                    $('#doc').html(data);


                }
            });
            var str = $("form").serialize();
//                $(".res").text(str);
        });
    });

This work for me